# custom permalinks based on taxonomies for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have products for which I want permalinks as following

```
https://example.com/product/manufacturer/brand/model
```

i.e

```
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-1/brand-1/model-11
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-1/brand-2/model-12
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-2/brand-3/model-23
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-2/brand-4/model-24
```

So to do this, I will create new custom post type "Product"

Also I want the:

archives of *manufacturer* with permalinks as

```
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-1/
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-2/
```

and

archives of *brands* with permalinks as

```
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-1/brand-1/
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-1/brand-2/
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-2/brand-3/
https://example.com/product/manufacturer-2/brand-4/
```

And I want to filter products by *brand* and *manufacturer*

So I was wondering what should I do regarding manufacturer and brand
Should I make

1. manufacturer and brand as custom post types ?
2. manufacturer and brand as separate custom taxonomies ?
3. manufacturer and brand as one custom taxonomy i.e manufactuere as top level taxonomy term and then brand as child term of manufactuere

SO please help and guide me how to proceed

thanks a lot for you inputs

Comment: The third approach seems the most sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Permalink structure is a hierarchy, each level should be descendent of one another, be more specific i.e. `shop.com/products/books/fiction/harry-potter` where every book is a product, fiction is a genre of books and Harry Potter belongs to fiction books.

So in your example `product/manufacturer/brand/model` every brand should belong to a single manufacturer and every model to a single brand **from** that manufacturer. If that is the case, just use a single taxonomy - product category and create a hierarchy.

If one brand can relate to more than one manufacturer you need separate taxonomies and your permalink structure has to be different.

Comment: thanks for help.. but fo you happend to have the code for this .. because the one I am trying is not working perfectly .. I will update it above